# How to sort an array by date key?

Tags: php

I have an array with key in "Y-m" format. I want to sort this array based on this key.

```
$array = array(
  "2018-10" => 239,
  "2018-11" => 264,
  "2018-12" => 237,
  "2019-01" => 211,
  "2019-04" => "0",
  "2019-03" => "0",
  "2019-02" => "0"
);
```

My final result should be like:

```
$array = array(
  "2019-04" => "0",
  "2019-03" => "0",
  "2019-02" => "0",
  "2019-01" => 211,
  "2018-12" => 237,
  "2018-11" => 264,
  "2018-10" => 239
);
```

This is the code so far I have tried.

```
$sorter = function($a, $b) {
            if (strtotime($a) == strtotime($b)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
        };

        uksort($array, $sorter);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like this using krsort() php function

```
$array = array(
  "2018-10" => 239,
  "2018-11" => 264,
  "2018-12" => 237,
  "2019-01" => 211,
  "2019-04" => "0",
  "2019-03" => "0",
  "2019-02" => "0"
);
krsort($array);
```

Working example:- https://3v4l.org/LqKa6

Comment: I made a demo for you ~ https://3v4l.org/9bC19

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: i think it should be krsort() my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The `ksort()` function sorts an associative array in ascending order, according to the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(
  "2018-10" => 239,
  "2018-11" => 264,
  "2018-12" => 237,
  "2019-01" => 211,
  "2019-04" => "0",
  "2019-03" => "0",
  "2019-02" => "0"
);

$date_keys = array_keys($array);

usort($date_keys,function($date1,$date2){
    $date_1 = new DateTime($date1);
    $date_2 = new DateTime($date2);
    if($date_1 > $date_2) return -1;
    else if($date_1 < $date_2) return 1;
    return 0;
});


$rearranged_data = [];
foreach($date_keys as $each_key){
    $rearranged_data[$each_key] = $array[$each_key];
}

$array = $rearranged_data;
print_r($array);
```

- First, retrieve date values using [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).
- Second, sort these date values using [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) by converting these to [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects and using comparison operators.
- Make a new array, loop over these sorted dates and fill in the values.
- In the end, reassign this rearranged data to the original array.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this.

```
$array = array();
foreach($sortedArray AS $key => $value){
        $key = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($key));
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
    // sort the new array on keys in reverse
    ksort($array);
```